# Why can I only add users from a trusted domain and not domain groups?

Tags: people-picker, trusted-domain

We have just set up a two-way trust with a remote domain.  I can add individual users to groups and assign permissions, but I can't add groups like 'domain users'.  It's very odd behaviour.  I can put type the group, like *UNDPPC\domain users* in the people-picker and if I hit OK I get an error:"The user does not exist or is not unique."  If I check the name before I hit OK it finds and underlines the name ok, but if I check again it's not found.

Individual users can be added fine.  Needless to say, the user search doesn't find anything.

I've tried adding the domain to the people-picker using stsadm searchadforests but don't seem to have had much luck.

Comment: I found this in the ULS:
Error in resolving user 's-1-5-21-20162213-2513311543-3581706507-513' : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007203A): The server is not operational.      
 at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)    
 at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()    
 at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()    
 at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)    
 etc., etc.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this question? Thanks

Comment: I don't really recall but I don't think so.